# Login problems on SQL EXPRESS using a user

Tags: sql-server, authentication

First time I set up a SQL server, so I hope you can help me out.

I have a problem regarding logging in using SQL auth on my SQL EXPRESS 2008. I have added a user though the management interface as you can see on the image below.

[image]

But as soon as I try to login using SQL auth I get an error the login failed for the user. The server log says:

```
Login failed for user 'zebisgaard'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: <named pipe>]
Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 5.
```

Do you have an idea why? I have triple checked that the username/password is correct, tried to recreate the user and so much more. And all this is localhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to ask, but are you REALLY sure that the username's correct?  I only mention it because the login name in your screenshot is different from the one in the error message.

Comment: Oh...my....god.... I have been trying this for 3 hours soon. I can not believe I made this error so many times. Wow. It must still be weekend in my head. I apologize for my stupidity!

Answer (score 0):

zebi **z** gaard is not the same as zebi **s** gaard.